# Cursor while loop never stop. what is wrong in this code?

Tags: sql, sybase

```
/*CREATE TABLE m_b (code VARCHAR(10),itemcount INT,type VARCHAR(30),amount  MONEY)        
insert into m_b values ('B001',1,'Dell',10)
insert into m_b values ('B001',1,'Dell',10)
insert into m_b values ('B001',1,'Apple',10)
insert into m_b values ('B001',2,'Apple',20)
insert into m_b values ('B001',2,'Apple',20)
insert into m_b values ('B114',1,'Apple',30.5)
insert into m_b values ('B114',1,'Apple',10) */

 --SELECT * INTO #temp FROM m_c  WHERE 1=2

DECLARE cur_test CURSOR 
 FOR SELECT Jobid,start,end_date,dayrate FROM m_c 

 go

DECLARE @Jobid INT
DECLARE @start DATE,@end_date DATE
DECLARE @dayrate INT 

OPEN cur_test
FETCH cur_test INTO @Jobid,@start,@end_date,@dayrate

--BEGIN 
DECLARE @jan INT

SET @jan=0

WHILE (@@sqlstatus != 2)

BEGIN

  IF month(@start)=1 
  BEGIN

    SELECT @jan= @jan + datediff(dd,'2013-01-31',@start)
    -- testing purpose
    INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (@jan,@start,@end_date,56)
  END 

  IF month(@end_date)=1 
  BEGIN

    SELECT @jan= @jan + datediff(dd,'2013-01-31',@end_date)
    -- testing purpose
    INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (@jan,@start,@end_date,57)

  END 

  FETCH cur_test INTO @Jobid,@start,@end_date,@dayrate

END


SELECT @jan

WAITFOR  delay '00:00:10'

CLOSE  cur_test

DEALLOCATE CURSOR cur_test
--END 

SELECT * FROM #temp

--TRUNCATE TABLE #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your never stop, but I always use below condition

```
while @@sqlstatus = 0
```

so try to use it instead of

```
WHILE (@@sqlstatus != 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the fetch status with this:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
```

Basing your cursor loop on the value of the data will mean an infinite loop if the exit value is never reached.